# Check if a Lead is converted after Salesforce Data entry in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am using the Salesforce Data event to trigger a journey when a new Lead is created.

After a certain wait time in the first decision split I am using the `IsConverted` field from the Contact Data attributes to see if they have converted. The field comes from the Synchronised Data Extension, `Lead_Salesforce`.

The check fails even after I convert them to a Person Account.

I check the Lead DE in Contact Builder after conversion and sync with Marketing Cloud and it is definitely set to `True`.

I thought using Contact Data instead of Journey Data is meant to use the data when that decision is evaluated, not in the state when the journey is fired.

What am i doing wrong?
How can i go about to remedying this?

Comment: What's Lead sync schedule frequency? 15 mins? And how much time you wait to evaluate decision split?

Comment: Sync is 15. I set a wait at 25 mins. Converted and checked it was true, nothing. Then checked with a 3 hour wait, still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In automation studio, you will need to create a query activity on the lead_salesforce DE to populate those records into a new DE, then add the new DE into the data designer. In journey builder, check against the data in the new DE (contact data > new DE). Take note of the lead sync frequency and the automation refresh interval and set your wait duration accordingly.